# Standard Java/Kotlin Regex for zipcode (alphanumeric +numeric) in edittext android

Tags: java, android, regex, kotlin, android-edittext

I am using an edit text for zipcode entry and was checking that it's alphanumeric and numeric. Which was previously working and sudden after months, I came to know that it's not working anymore. Seeking a method/sample code which can help me in this.

This is what I have tried so far

```
private fun isLettersOrDigits(chars: String): Boolean {
    val numRegex = ".*[0-9].*"
    val alphaRegex = ".*[A-Za-z].*"
    return chars.matches(numRegex.toRegex()) && chars.matches(alphaRegex.toRegex())
}

when
    isLettersOrDigits(string) - > {please enter alphanumeric value}
```

Any help would be highly appreciable. 
thank you :)

Comment: I think you want `\w*` or `[A-Za-z0-9]*` instead of those 2 separate regexps. They'll match as long as you have 1 number and 1 letter somewhere in your string, which is probably not what you want

Comment: So what could be the best regex for alphanumeric and numeric value validation sir? @us

Comment: I'd suggest `chars.all { it.isLetterOrDigit }` actually

Comment: `\w` denotes [a-zA-Z0-9] so yes, that's the most appropriate for your needs